# Is it possible that accuracy get reduced while increasing the no of epochs?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am training a DNN in MATLAB , while optimizing my network, I am observing a decrement in accuracy while increasing the epochs. Is it possible?
The loss values in on the other hand decreases during training while increasing epochs. Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tldr; absolutely.

When entire training dataset is seen once by the model (feed forwarded once), it's termed as 1 epoch.

The below graph shows the general behaviour of accuracy with the number of epochs. Training on more number of epochs can result in low accuracy on validation, even though loss will continue to reduce (training accuracy will be high). This is termed as overfitting.
No. of epochs to train also a hyperparameter that needs fine tuning.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much.... plz suggest what to do, what I am grasping is the point at which I am getting maximum accuracy in validation should be taken as optimum no of epochs?

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible:

1. Especially when you are training in batches
2. When your learning rate is too high

Comment: But when I m reducing LR the accuracy further decreses.